# WPF: Viewbox and TranslatePoint

Tags: wpf, viewbox

1. I have a Viewbox with a Canvas Child,
2. I have the Stretch property of Viewbox to Fill,
3. I have changed the width and height of the Viewbox,
4. I need to get the location of children in Canvas with respect to Viewbox parent
   I tried :

   Point p = viewboxInstance.TranslatePoint(new Point(Canvas.GetLeft(child), Canvas.GetTop(child)), viewboxInstanceParent);

it gets wrong coordinates!
Is there a solution or work around ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The `ViewBox` does not change any properties of its children including `Canvas` left and top values.  You need to use the actual coordinates of the child, not just the attached property values.

You can call `TranslatePoint` directly on the child as long as it's a `UIElement`.  To reference the top-left point of the child, you can use (0, 0) which is the default for `Point` so `new Point()` is enough.

```
        Point p = child.TranslatePoint(new Point(), viewboxInstanceParent);
```

good luck,

EDIT:
Here's a video of this code in action: [ViewboxChildPosition](http://tinypic.com/player.php?v=2hmdb0l&s=5)

Comment: no, it didn't work, it seams that Viewbox always treats internal content as they were not streched when dealing with TranslatePoint

I solved it with perspective transformation math, QuadToQuad matrix

Comment: I've added a link to a video that shows my results.  Sorry if this doesn't work for you. If you have something that does, you should post it and mark is as the answer for others that might have the same problem.